# FOREIGN KEY - execute table

Tags: mysql

Do you know where in Foreign key I have got problem?

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(  `countryId` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  `personId` bigint(20) NOT ' at line 1
```

Table1 with Foreign key

```
ALTER TABLE `country` (
  `countryId` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `personId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(5000) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`countryId`),
  UNIQUE KEY `personId` (`personId`),
  CONSTRAINT fk_PerOrders FOREIGN KEY (`personId`) REFERENCES perosn(`PersonId`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 PACK_KEYS=0;
```

Table2

```
CREATE TABLE `perosn` (
  `PersonId` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(5000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Surname` varchar(5000) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PersonId`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 PACK_KEYS=0;
```

Comment: Your first statement has `ALTER TABLE`, it should be `CREATE TABLE`

Comment: And if you want to have `FOREIGN KEY` constraints, define your tables with `InnoDB` engine, not `MyISAM`.

Comment: And why the ultra extra long varchar columns? I know neither of a country which requires a 5000 characters name nor a person with so long name or surname.

Comment: @ypercube this is only example :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE `country` (
^^^^^--- should be CREATE

CREATE TABLE `perosn` (
              ^^^^^^--- should be person
```

Comment: My table exist and I have to use ALTER. I change references but all the time I have got error

Comment: but you're using create table syntax. ALTER syntax is MUCH different. that's why you're getting the error. RTLM: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

Comment: I don`t know why but when I execute this code this position is not added (CONSTRAINT fk_PerOrders FOREIGN KEY (`personId`) REFERENCES perosn(`PersonId`))

Comment: You're using MyISAM tables anyways, which do not support foreign keys (the syntax is parsed/accepted, but FKs are not enforced).

Comment: do you know what I should do? to have FK? bacause I need them.

Comment: switch to InnoDB tables instead. There's very few reasons to use myisam tables these days. And note you're still using `perosn` in your "this position is not added" message above. You've got the `o` and `s` swapped.